# Wrap .Net ArrayList with custom VBA class get iterator

Tags: .net, vba, for-loop, arraylist, com

I just discovered that I can create some .Net classes from VBA using the CreateObject method which can create COM classes.  This is pretty cool but the created class is late bound so you don't get any intellisense etc.  So what I hoped to do was write VBA wrapper classes and delegate all the method calls to an internal reference to the .Net object.

So this works well for an ArrayList object for everything but trying to reference the enumerator.  There is a hack for VBA which allows you to create your own collections and use the For Each ... syntax to enumerate your collections.  The following is an example:

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"
    Set NewEnum = <<< pass a reference to the enumerator here.
End Property
```

Most implementations hold a reference to a VBA Collection object and pass the enumerator for the Collection object.  However since I am holding a .Net ArrayList I'd like to pass that out.  However I get "Invalid procedure call or argument" when I try.

My current attempt is this:

```
Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Dim enumerator As Object
    Set enumerator = internalList.GetEnumerator()    <<<< Error occurs here.
    Set NewEnum = enumerator
End Function
```

I'm pretty sure that its possible to make this work because it is possible to iterate the ArrayList collection directly without the wrapper.  E.g.

```
Public Sub TestCreateArrayList()
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    list.Add "an item."
    list.Add "another item."

    Dim Item As Variant
    For Each Item In list
        Debug.Print Item
    Next
End Sub
```

I can live without the For Each functionality but it would be nice if I could get it to work especially when it seems like its almost there.

Edit:
Its probably worth mentioning that instantiating an ArrayList and then calling GetEnumerator yields the same error even outside of a wrapper class.

Further edit:
Note that trying to set a variable of type IUnknown to the result of the GetEnumerator method still gives the same error.

```
Public Sub TestCreateArrayList()
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim iterator As IUnknown
    Set iterator = list.GetEnumerator()   <<<< error occurs here.
End Sub
```

Final Edit:
Thanks to @RegEdit's comments below I was able to get this to work and thought I'd add the code:

```
Private internalList As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ' create a .Net Array list for the internal data store.
    Set internalList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If Not internalList Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        internalList.Dispose
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub

Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
        Dim enumerator As IUnknown
        Set enumerator = internalList.GetEnumerator(0, internalList.Count)
        Set NewEnum = enumerator
End Function

' ... other wrapped methods elided
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a derived class from ArrayList with an extra method like this: `[DispId(-4)] public IEnumerator GetMyEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }`, and get MyEnumerator instead of GetEnumerator?

Comment: @SimonMourier VBA does not support inheritance. You can't derive from other classes I am afraid.

Comment: I'm not talking about the VBA side, but the .NET side. Also, add the ComVisible(true) attribute to the new derived class.

Comment: You are helping too much.  A System.Collections.IEnumerator is automatically mapped to a COM enumerator (IEnumVARIANT).  Just expose a method that returns IEnumerator (call GetEnumerator in its implementation) and you're set to For Each.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes you are right, the IEnumerable interface has the correct COM setup.  However the call to GetEnumerator fails with the above method.  See edited code above.

Comment: Stop using IUnknown.

Comment: Very Nice!  FYI: Having a default property return the `internalList ` will yield the same results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use

```
 Dim enumerator As Object
```

you are declaring a COM object. But COM implements IEnumerator as `IEnumVARIANT`, which inherits `IUnknown` directly, and COM is not happy trying to set the `GetEnumerator` return value into an `Object`. Instead, you can use

```
Dim enumerator As IEnumVARIANT
```

**EDIT:** Note that although `ArrayList` implements `IEnumerable`, [it overloads `GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.ArrayList.GetEnumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) with a method that takes `index` and `count`. So you have to use the `Nothing` keyword in VBA when you want to call the overload with no parameters.

```
Set iterator = list.GetEnumerator(Nothing, Nothing)
```

You can see that it's working, because if you include your original lines of code that add two items to the list, and then use a call such as

```
Set iterator = list.GetEnumerator(1, 3) ' 3 is out of bounds
```

you now get a new (expected) error informing you that offset/length are out of bounds.

Comment: Cool, I think you're right.  However changing the variable type to IEnumVARIANT or IUnknown still fails.  Try:Public Sub TestCreateArrayList()
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim iterator As IEnumVARIANT
    Set iterator = list.GetEnumerator()
End Sub

Comment: @Rossco ah, forgot to mention, that's because `ArrayList` has an overloaded `GetEnumerator`. I've updated my answer to explain about this.

Comment: @RegEdit you are a legend.  That was exactly the problem!  I didn't even consider that VBA might try to use the overloaded method.  I thought if I supply no arguments that it would try to use the one with no arguments.  So I use: Set iterator = list.GetEnumerator(0, internalList.Count)